# Сказуемое в предложении "Его уже нет в городе"

Tags: синтаксис

*Его уже нет в городе.*

Искала на саите подобные вопросы и прочитала различные ответы:
в одном ответе стоит, что "сказуемое выражено словом *нет*", в другом - "сказуемое опущено". 
Поэтому спрашиваю еще раз: где все-таки сказуемое? 
Если глагол в этом предложении все-таки отсутствует, можно тем не менее сказать, что это предложение в изъявительном наклонении?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет - это по происхождению "не есть", **употребляется в качестве сказуемого в настоящем времени (изъявительное наклонение).**

В прошедшем времени  и в сослагательном наклонении употребляется форма "не было" и "не было бы", в будущем времени (изъявительное наклонение)  - форма "не будет".

Есть время.  - Нет времени. Не было времени. Не будет времени Не было бы времени.  Время - грамматический субъект, предложения с отрицанием - безличные предложения.

Из книги: Кустова Г.И. Синтаксис современного русского языка.

Comment: Sibylla, а что Вы скажете про это предложение: Без него я как без рук. (я расширяю его и добавляю "я как будто бы осталась без рук"). Можно сказать, что если в этом предложении стоял глагол, он был бы в сосл. накл.?

Comment: Это простое предложение, сказуемое составное именное, именная часть выражена сравнительным оборотом, связка в настоящем времени пропущена. Но связка БЫТЬ может использоваться в форме прошедшего и будущего времени,  а также в сослагательном наклонении:  Без него я была (буду,  была бы) как без рук.

Comment: Sibilla, простите, что беспокою Вас еще раз: не могу определить сказуемое в придаточном "Вероятно, что конец всей истории совсем близко." Связка там тоже пропущена?

Comment: Да, связка в форме настоящего времени пропущена, именная часть сказуемого выражена  наречием "близко". Но вот другие формы связки       (был, будет, был бы) вроде бы не подходят, так как не сочетаются с опорным словом "вероятно"  со значением предположения, Вообще для придаточных изъяснительных существуют  определенные ограничения в выборе форм сказуемого, что определяется в конкретных случаях по ситуации.

Comment: огромное спасибо! Вы ангел!!!!!!!